# Data is unloaded from View Controller when segue happens

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two screens that I am performing a push segue between. In the first screen, there are 5 buttons that you click on to send you to the next page. On the next page, you edit some information that is specific to each button, then you click a button and get sent back to the first screen. (Kind of like editing contacts) When I edit one button it works perfectly. However, when I click on the next button and edit its information, when I come back the original screen has lost the information about the first button. Just to be clear, I am not actually editing the button. There is information that is being displayed on the button, but I am storing data in some properties on the view controller.
[image: Storyboard]

I think the problem is that the data stored in the properties is being cleared when I perform the segue. How can I make it so that the data persists?

Comment: Could you paste some code of your first page view controller?

Comment: Segues, other than unwinds, always instantiate new controllers. You should only go back to a previous controller with an unwind, or by popping in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @rdelmar, I am now using a modal segue from the first view. I then use dismissViewControllerAnimated to go back. (Found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003380/segue-unwind-back-to-the-last-specific-view-controller) question.)